# Azure Conditional Access limitations - Unable to secure MS Cloud accounts

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory, identity

To respond to new cloud account vulnerabilities (cloud service/privileged account use username/password) tried to constrain access to these principals only from on-premises network using Conditional Access.
Unfortunately Location limitations allow:

- Max ~45 IP Named Locations and then throws error "You have exceeded the maximum allowed storage for named locations. Try again with a shorter list."

  - *Max 10 IP Ranges per Location (has to close window and open again to add more)

Any ideas how to overcome this limitation?
Certificate would be also an option but it is not supported by all O365 systems for automation (i.e. mainly PoSH, rarely Graph API).

Answer (score 0):

The number of named locations you can configure is constrained by the size of the related object in Azure AD. You can configure:

- One named location with up to 1200 IP ranges.
- A maximum of 90 named locations with one IP range assigned to each of
  them.

Ref [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition).